# Universal property of relative proj in simple situations?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On the stacks project they have a complicated universal property for Proj: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01NS

Presumably, at least some of the complexity there is due to the insistence on working in very general circumstances. In most of the relative proj examples I have computed recently (blow ups, projective bundles), one can impose a lot of simplifying conditions - assuming that the base scheme is a variety, assuming that the $QCoh$ is finitely generated in degree $1$...

Is there a simple statement one can make under reasonable hypothesis?

Comment: The special case http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01O4 seems pretty clean compared to the general one? Does this not meet your criterion from simple? It's analogous to the universal property of $\mathrm{Proj}(S)$ when $S$ is generated over $S_0$ by $S_1$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Yeah, that is great, thanks! It still seems like the relative proj constructions is much easier to work with by gluing patches and studying transition maps, at least for the examples I have been studying so far... can you think of some situation in which the universal property is easier to use?

Comment: Dear @AreaMan, I think it depends on what you want to do. In the theory of relatively ample sheaves, one wants to connect the ampleness connection to the existence of morphisms to (relative) $\mathrm{Proj}$, and here the description of the functor of points of $\mathrm{Proj}$ in terms of invertible sheaves is useful, see http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01VJ.